# Automount various USB stick file systems on Jessie Lite

Tags: usb, filesystem, mount, jessie-lite

I want to be able to automount USB sticks *fat32* and *ntfs* formatted on the fly, like hot-plugging without rebooting the my Raspberry Pi 2. I have **ntfs-3g** installed on **jessie-lite**.

Putting the UUID in `fstab` is not an option because I'd have to find the UUID of every device. I want to be able to plug different USB devices with different file-formats in and mount them automatically. Is this possible?

Also I once nearly got it working with the `usbmount` program. I could access my drive for a second before getting the error `transport endpoint is not connected`. I reinstalled the program but then I never even got to that point again, not even with the error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After alot of research I could fix my Problem with usbmount:

### Adding ntfs to usbmount

1. Install usbmount with `sudo apt-get install usbmount`.
2. Install NTFS driver package **ntfs-3g** with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`.
3. Configure usbmount to mount specified filesystems by opening the usbmount file with `sudo nano /etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`.

In here there is a line called `FILESYSTEMS=""`. Only filesystems specified in this line are mounted via usbmount, so we change it to : `FILESYSTEMS="vfat ntfs fuseblk ext2 ext3 ext4 hfsplus"`

If you want usbmount to mount NTFS Filesystems, be sure to add
**ntfs** and **fuseblk** to the line. NTFS devices are sometimes listed as *fusblk* by the ntfs-3g package, so those two are the same. I don't really know why though.

Also, if you don't add **fuseblk** in the configuration, unplugged NTFS Devices will **not** automatically unmount. They will stay mounted and keep the folder they are mounted to until the device is manually unmounted with `unmount /dev/sda1`  --> *where sda1 could be another variable*.

The next important line is `FS_MOUNTOPTIONS=""`. Here you specify which filesystems should be mounted and how they should be mounted.

We change it to: `FS_MOUNTOPTIONS="-fstype=ntfs-3g,nls=utf8,umask=007,gid=46
-fstype=fuseblk,nls=utf8,umask=007,gid=46 -fstype=vfat,gid=1000,uid=1000,umask=007"`

With this the filesystems **vfat** (fat32) **ntfs-3g** (NTFS), and
**fuseblk** (NTFS again) are mounted. I think most parameters can stay the same. Again here just add ntfs-3g (**add ntfs-3g not ntfs**) and fuseblk to be able to mount all NTFS Files. For more filesystems add more lines starting with `-fstype=`.

### Keep NTFS mounted untill device is unplugged

Here is a solution for the problem, when the mounted NTFS drive is only accessible for a few seconds. This fix comes from **Christian Weinberger**.

1. Create the file **usbmount.rules** in **/etc/udev/rules.d/** with `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/usbmount.rules`.

This is the content:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", DRIVERS=="sbp2",         ACTION=="add",  PROGRAM="/bin/systemd-escape -p --template=usbmount@.service $env{DEVNAME}", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="%c"
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",       ACTION=="add",  PROGRAM="/bin/systemd-escape -p --template=usbmount@.service $env{DEVNAME}", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="%c"
KERNEL=="ub*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",       ACTION=="add",  PROGRAM="/bin/systemd-escape -p --template=usbmount@.service $env{DEVNAME}", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="%c"
KERNEL=="sd*",                          ACTION=="remove",       RUN+="/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount remove"
KERNEL=="ub*",                          ACTION=="remove",       RUN+="/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount remove"
```

1. Create the file **usbmount@.service** in **/etc/systemd/system/** with `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/usbmount@.service`.

This is the content:

```
[Unit]
BindTo=%i.device
After=%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutStartSec=0
Environment=DEVNAME=%I
ExecStart=/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

Now reboot and check with `cat /etc/mtab` to which folder the usb devices are mounted to. By Default they are mountet to **/media/usbstick0**.

Source:

[Christians Fix](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=774149)

[Why fusblk?](http://www.archivum.info/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/2010-04/07961/Bug-570405-usbmount-USBmount-does-not-unmount-NTFS-drives.html)

Comment: This solution needs a couple more steps, see my answer.

Comment: @f-untermoser: Could you please have a look at my question regarding usbmount here: https://superuser.com/questions/1603086/usbmount-does-not-unmount-vfat-mount-point ?

Comment: Will this also work with "exfat" devices?

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Untermoser is correct, but it will break some of usbmount functionality.

Because he is using Systemd units to spawn processes to mount (to enable NTFS), the environment variable `$DEVPATH` is no longer sent to `usbmount add` command, resulting in the symlink creation failure.

To fix that, run the following:

```
sed -i '/# Determine vendor/,/if/ s/\(.*vendor=\)/if [ -z "$DEVPATH" ]; then DEVPATH="$(udevadm info --query=path --name=\/$DEVNAME)"; fi\n\1/g' /usr/share/usbmount/usbmount
```

The command above recreates `$DEVPATH` if it's not available.

There's also another bug in usbmount, with respect to `usbmount remove`. It loops over mountpoints, and the one that is defined in usmount config is unmounted. However, if a match is found but is not in that list, remove breaks and does nothing. This is particularly crucial if you create multiple mountpoints for one USB, because usbmount sees the first and does nothing.

To fix, the following change is needed:

```
sed -i '/umount.d ||/,/break/ s/break.*//; /umount.d ||/,/done/ s/:/:\n\t\tbreak 2/' /usr/share/usbmount/usbmount
```

This will move the break inside the inner loop (where success is guaranteed, and break 2 steps out).

Answer (score 1):

For those that are trying to get the same to work on the newer Stretch (Lite) and are finding that the answers by Untermoser and AlbiusX don't unmount vfat drives, you'll need to follow these extra steps in addition to their provided answers:

Run the following command in terminal:

`sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service.d/`

This will create the required folders needed. Next, create a conf file here, e.g:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service.d/shared-mount-ns.conf`

Inside this file add the following lines:

`[Service]
MountFlags=shared`

This will change systemd-udevd's default behavior of private filesystem namespaces to use shared ones, which is equivalent to the behavior of udev in jessie.

(Sourced from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330094/udev-rule-to-mount-disk-does-not-work/330156#330156)

Comment: So this was the problem all along -- I was looking at outdated docs. Am running `Linux raspberrypi 4.14.79-v7+` on the Pi, for reference